# ValueError expected 2 got 1 discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
    @commands.command()
    @has_permissions(ban_members=True)
    async def unban(self, ctx, *, member):

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Unban", description=f"Unbanned - {member}", colour=discord.Colour.purple())

        banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
        member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

        for ban_entry in banned_users:
            user = ban_entry.user

            if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
                await ctx.guild.unban(user)

                if (member_name, member_discriminator) in banned_users:
                    await ctx.send(f'Error unbanning {member.mention}.')
                    return
                else:
                    pass

                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                print(f'{current_time} {member} has been unbanned by @{ctx.message.author}. Server Name: {ctx.guild.name}, Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}\n')
                with open('textfiles/text-logs/unban-log.txt', 'a') as unbanlog:
                    unbanlog.writelines(f'{current_time} {member} has been unbanned by @{ctx.message.author}. Server Name: {ctx.guild.name}, Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}\n')
                return
```

I am trying to make it so it checks if a user has been unbanned before it sends the message that they have been unbanned. But I keep on getting ValueError

Here is the exact error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ajkit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\ajkit\Desktop\Programming\Python\discord.py\Galactia\cogs\ModeratorTools.py", line 105, in unban
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ajkit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\ajkit\Desktop\Programming\Python\discord.py\Galactia\cogs\ErrorHandling.py", line 21, in on_command_error
    raise Error
  File "C:\Users\ajkit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\ajkit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ajkit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: This means that there wasn't a `"#"` in the `member` argument

Comment: So what would I change?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest converting the member argument to a Member object like so. You can then use the attributes of a `discord.Member` object for discriminator and etc.

```py
async def unban(self, ctx, member:commands.MemberConverter):
```

You can retrieve the discriminator by doing `member.discriminator` and their name by using `member.name`. Check out the [`discord.Member` docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member).

I also suggest just checking if the user and member are the same or not instead of checking their discriminator and name.

```py
if user == member:
```

You should also delete the exception handling if unbanning doesn't work. This is because if it doesn't unban properly, it will automatically raise an error.

Then, in the strings at the end, cast `member` to type string so that it is readable.

In total, the implementation would look something like this:

```
@commands.command()
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(self, ctx, member:commands.MemberConverter):

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Unban", description=f"Unbanned - {member}", colour=discord.Colour.purple())

    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if user == member:
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            print(f'{current_time} {str(member)} has been unbanned by @{ctx.message.author}. Server Name: {ctx.guild.name}, Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}\n')
            with open('textfiles/text-logs/unban-log.txt', 'a') as unbanlog:
                unbanlog.writelines(f'{current_time} {str(member)} has been unbanned by @{ctx.message.author}. Server Name: {ctx.guild.name}, Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}\n')
            return
```

Comment: When I do all of that it completely breaks

Comment: @Axkkzy Hmm weird, let me try putting the entire implementation.

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea how converters work so I still have a long way to go. Thanks for helping me out